# Calling a VBScript using arguments

Tags: vbscript, arguments

I am trying to get a VBScript to launch another VBScript while passing an argument from the first one to the second one. I got the part of how to receive the argument on the second script, however I have no clue how to call it within the first VBScript. Here is what I currently have in the first one:

```
arg1 = "MyArgument"
objShell.Run "ArgumentTest2.vbs arg1"
```

When I run the this script, it gives me the error message:

Script: C:\Argument Test 1.vbs
Line: 2
Char: 1
Error: Object required 'objShell'
Code: 800A01A8
Source: Microsoft VBScript runtime error

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize `objShell` with

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

before you can use its `.Run` method.

Also, VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings, so you'll need to concatenate your argument to the rest of the command string:

```
objShell.Run "ArgumentTest2.vbs " & arg1
```

Note that you'll need to put tokens in double quotes if they contain spaces:

```
arg1 = "My Argument"
objShell.Run "ArgumentTest2.vbs """ & arg1 & """"
```

Comment: @Ansgar 'Eagle Eyes' W. Thanks for the improvement!